# Finding bottlenecks in application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, profiling

I have an .NET app and it runs fast through about 2000 records that starts to go really slow. I'm trying to find the bottleneck and I was wondering if there is a good, possibly free but it doesn't have to be, tool or a way to find the bottleneck. I'm trying to find a list that isn't cleared out but I don't see it yet. I have VS 2008.

Comment: You might want to take a look at WinDbg and SoS - http://windbg.dumpanalysis.org/ You can take a memory dump of the application when it slows down and analyse it for unreleased resources

Comment: Is there any code you can post?

Comment: Try some of the steps detailed in this question I answered previously: [Profiling and optimisation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426384/many-methods-kill-code-speed/3426401#3426401)

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio do you have?  In VS2008 Development/Suite editions, there is a built-in profiler for both native and managed code (disclosure: I'm on the team that built it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to start running some [performance counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/performance-counters-portal) to monitor CPU usage and memory stats and figure out what's going on.

If that doesn't lead you to any obvious answers, it's time to start profiling.

[JetBrains dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) has a 30 day free trial. It's a pretty decent memory and performance profiler you might want to check out.

Microsoft's [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=86ce6052-d7f4-4aeb-9b7a-94635beebdda&displaylang=en) is free.

If you're still coming up with nothing, it's time to break out the big guns: [WinDbg](https://web.archive.org/web/20110217084226/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx). If you get this far, you'll find [Tess' blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/) extremely helpful.

Comment: +1 Good references.  [.Net Framework 4 Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273)

Answer (score 6):

There is a very good free tool, and you already have it. It's only disadvantage is that it may not be intuitive, to begin with.

When the program is acting slow, pause it under the IDE. Examine the call stack. (I turn off the display of arguments; I'm only interested in the specific lines of code. I copy the whole stack out to a text editor, like notepad.) Do this several times. The slower it is, the fewer samples you're going to need before you see the problem.

If you see one or more statements that are suspiciously popular, like they appear on a healthy fraction of samples (at least two), you should pay attention to those. What I do is take a few more samples until they show up, because I want to understand why they are being executed. That's important, because if I could replace them by something that took a lot less time, I would save a large fraction.

I'll try to explain why it works.
First, the common concept of "bottleneck" is seriously misleading.
Software isn't slow because it has constrictions or "hot" places.
Of course it can have cache misses and so on, but the dominant reason
it is slow is that it is doing more than it needs to - often a *lot* more.

It goes off on wild nested function call junkets,
with justifications more and more remote.
This shows up as a call tree that is far more bushy than necessary.
All you have to do is find big branches that you can prune off.
That is what the pausing technique does.

So while you're rummaging around for the tool that will help you play detective to locate the elusive "bottleneck", be a tree surgeon, and prune the heaviest branches you can from the call tree, as found by pausing, and keep doing it until you can't.

It's good to be skeptical, but you may be surprised how well it works.

Comment: Or, you could just use a profiler which will record your call trees for each thread with lots of useful statistics you won't get from the IDE.

Comment: @Winston: Not to argue, but it won't record your call trees (that's impossible) and it gives you lots of statistics, but they generally do *not* point you at the problems. The best profilers (IMO) are such as Zoom, which sample call stacks (on wall-clock time) and tell you for per line (not per function) the % of stack samples containing the line. "Self time", call counts, average call duration, are common statistics, and are useless, as are call graphs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/adamcalderon/archive/2007/11/08/22470.aspx) from Adam Calderon links to some MSDN blog pages on profiling.

However, most (if not all) of them seem to be about Visual Studio Team System. So if you have access to that version of the software you get some tools "for free".

Comment: So sad. I just read (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2007/09/14/pinpoint-a-performance-issue-using-hotpath-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx)
If you want to be a Giga-dollar company, sell people what they think they want, not what works. Their "hotpath" is based on the idea that what you are looking for is places where the CPU spends much time (hotspots, or places with high exclusive cost). It totally ignores poorly justified intermediate call sites, and it is blind to I/O. They should use real apps (lots of low-level I/O, big data structure). Mandelbrot is an unrepresentative toy.

Answer (score 0):

DevPartner for C++ my MicroFocus (Formerly Compuware) has a performance profiler that was halfway decent.
Intel makes V-Tune that does the same thing. ( I think it's Intel... I've never used it).
My favorite is the one that comes with Visual Studio Team Edition. It's great.
You should also instrument your own code, and write automated tests as well so you can compare one build to the next.